# Load dynamic values into msgHTML in phpmailer body from database

Tags: php, sql, foreach, phpmailer

What I am trying doing here is inserting and sending the number of orders via SMTP phpmailer.
 I am using foreach to separate the order data into key value pair and inserting into the database.

**can see here:** 
[image: here]

once the execution is successful now I want to send a mail to the owner with the order details which is just inserted. Just for a test I only picked **productid** as a order detail.

**Here is the mail that just arrived.**
[image: here]

**Problem**

What I am looking is the database has inserted 2 productid (26,27) but in mail i only got productid (26) I want the dynamic productid insertion inside the mail body. I use while loop but I thing the goal cannot achieve or fulfill. I would be appreciate if anyone printout where I am getting wrong.

**PHP:**

```
$shown = false;
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $number => $val)
            {
                       // prepare and bind
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchase(guest_code,productid,quantity,date_purchase) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $stmt->bind_param("siis",$_SESSION['CODE'],$val['product_id'],$val['product_quantity'],$current_date_time); //inserting mutiple value in db successful.

                        if($stmt->execute())
                        {
                            if(!$shown) //show msg or dedirect only once
                            {      

                                    $sql= mysqli_query($conn,"select productid from purchase where guest_code='".$_SESSION['CODE']."'"); //fetch only productid for test
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
                                    {
                                          $productid = $row['productid'];
                                          $message = "<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><strong>".$productid."</td></tr>";
                                          $mail->msgHTML($message); //trying to load multiple productid in $message 
                                    }    

                                        $mail->Subject = 'New Order Arrived!';
                                        if(!$mail->send()) 
                                        {
                                          $mail_error = 'error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                          exit();
                                        } 
                                        else {
                                               //if mail sent then
                                                unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]); //distroy all the values in the cart
                                                //header('location:../checkout.php?er=false');
                                        }


                                $shown = true;

                            }


                        }else
                        {

                            if(!$shown) //show msg only once
                            {
                                echo 'ERROR: while placing your order. Please contact restaurant owner.';
                                $shown = true;
                            }
                        }


            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every time you call `$mail->msgHTML($message);` it *replaces* the entire contents of `Body`; it doesn't *add* to it. I would expect you do something along the lines of:

```php
$mail->Body = '<p>Your order</p><table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $productid = $row['productid'];
    $mail->Body .= "<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><strong>".$productid."</td></tr>";
}
$mail->Body .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Not working... this is what i got in mail `<p>Your order</p><table><tr><td style='text-align:center;'><strong>26</td></tr></table>`

Comment: That's working exactly as intended. If your query is not returning all the products that you want, then your query is wrong. If it finds more rows, they will all be included.

Comment: yes you were right about this the returning all the products.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that I find.**

So, the problem that I encountering before was calling the `sendmail()` function inside the `foreach()` and on the top of that, to show the message only once I was using the if condition which was preventing the `$row['productid']` to display only one productID and as a result reviving mail with the productID in return.

**Instead I have to do something like this:**

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]) && $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]!=='')
{
 $shown = 0;
 foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $number => $val)
            {


                        // prepare and bind
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchase(guest_code,productid,quantity,date_purchase) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $stmt->bind_param("siis",$_SESSION['CODE'],$val['product_id'],$val['product_quantity'],$current_date_time); //inserting mutiple value in db successful.

                        if($stmt->execute())
                        {

                                $body .=  '<p><b>Product ID:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$val['product_id'].'</p>';   
                                $body .= '<p><b>Discussion Name:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$val['product_quantity'].'</p>'; 
                                echo 'success';     

                        }else
                        {

                            if($shown==0) //show msg only once
                            {
                                echo 'ERROR: while placing your order. Please contact restaurant owner.';
                                header('location:../checkout.php?er=true');
                                $shown = 1;
                            }
                        }


            }

      $mail->msgHTML($body);
      $mail->Subject = 'New Order Arrived!';
      $mail->send();


}
```

**Mail Output:**

[image: here]